# Retrieving Subscriber List Status using Fuel SOAP API

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api, fuel

I'm trying to figure out how to use the SOAP API to check if a Subscriber has unsubscribed from any List that they appear on.

I'm using the example SOAP envelope provided for [Retrieving All Lists a Subscriber is On](https://help.exacttarget.com/en/technical_library/web_service_guide/technical_articles/retrieving_all_lists_a_subscriber_is_on/) but I don't get the subscription status in the response. Any ideas?

### Request

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <fueloauth xmlns="http://exacttarget.com">accessTokenHere</fueloauth>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <RetrieveRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
         <RetrieveRequest>
            <ObjectType>ListSubscriber</ObjectType>
            <Properties>ListID</Properties>
            <Properties>Status</Properties>
            <Filter xsi:type="ns1:SimpleFilterPart" xmlns:ns1="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
               <Property>SubscriberKey</Property>
               <SimpleOperator>equals</SimpleOperator>
               <Value>999999</Value>
            </Filter>
         </RetrieveRequest>
      </RetrieveRequestMsg>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

### Response

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing"
    xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"
    xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
    <soap:Header>
        <wsa:Action>RetrieveResponse</wsa:Action>
        <wsa:MessageID>urn:uuid:a70527a2-79b8-4ed2-b3ec-5adb828620c1</wsa:MessageID>
        <wsa:RelatesTo>urn:uuid:8686747c-f7cc-459b-8256-2603eb13e3a2</wsa:RelatesTo>
        <wsa:To>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/role/anonymous</wsa:To>
        <wsse:Security>
            <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="Timestamp-56623383-47ec-4cf0-b6e4-67cc30e1427e">
                <wsu:Created>2015-01-29T03:45:13Z</wsu:Created>
                <wsu:Expires>2015-01-29T03:50:13Z</wsu:Expires>
            </wsu:Timestamp>
        </wsse:Security>
    </soap:Header>
    <soap:Body>
        <RetrieveResponseMsg
            xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
            <OverallStatus>OK</OverallStatus>
            <RequestID>2035f0c1-1ec7-41e2-a1db-b40c3a5ac399</RequestID>
            <Results xsi:type="ListSubscriber">
                <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true" />
                <ObjectID xsi:nil="true" />
                <ListID>372</ListID>
            </Results>
            <Results xsi:type="ListSubscriber">
                <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true" />
                <ObjectID xsi:nil="true" />
                <ListID>13638</ListID>
            </Results>
        </RetrieveResponseMsg>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried using another users' credentials to make the same request (in my original question) and I received a response with the subscriber status, so it must be a user-based permission issue. Thanks Adam and Gaurav for your assistance.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing this property in your SOAP envelope

```
<Properties>SubscriberKey</Properties>
```

You have just added it as a filter without first setting it as a property. That should fix it.

Comment: Hello Gaurav, that does not work. I deliberately did not include that property in my request as I don't need the `SubscriberKey` (it's in my filter, so I know what the `SubscriberKey` is). However if I do include it, I get **exactly the same response** as above. The Subscriber Status is not returned in the response.

Comment: I've always found it useful to return Subscriber key ad it helps track the results and match subscribers, I agree that API returns unexpected results sometimes and would strongly recommend raising a support case.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try specifying *all* of the retrievable properties for the [ListSubscriber](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/technical_library/web_service_guide/objects/listsubscriber/) object.

- Client.ID
- Client.PartnerClientKey
- CreatedDate
- ID
- ListID
- ModifiedDate
- ObjectID
- Status
- List item
- SubscriberKey

I was able to retrieve the status by list with the properties above.

**Request**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
   <s:Header>
      <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">Retrieve</a:Action>
      <a:MessageID>urn:uuid:6e8a12c5-dd24-456b-80d0-582d5506b867</a:MessageID>
      <a:ReplyTo>
         <a:Address>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/role/anonymous</a:Address>
      </a:ReplyTo>
      <a:To s:mustUnderstand="1">https://webservice.exacttarget.com/Service.asmx</a:To>
      <o:Security xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" s:mustUnderstand="1">
         <u:Timestamp u:Id="_0">
            <u:Created>2015-01-29T17:47:15.716Z</u:Created>
            <u:Expires>2015-01-29T17:52:15.716Z</u:Expires>
         </u:Timestamp>
         <o:UsernameToken u:Id="uuid-1c0f4e43-a32f-4f4d-8fcf-1cd220265fde-3">
            <o:Username>XXXXXXXX</o:Username>
            <o:Password>XXXXXXXX</o:Password>
         </o:UsernameToken>
      </o:Security>
   </s:Header>
   <s:Body xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <RetrieveRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
         <RetrieveRequest>
            <ObjectType>ListSubscriber</ObjectType>
            <Properties>Client.ID</Properties>
            <Properties>Client.PartnerClientKey</Properties>
            <Properties>CreatedDate</Properties>
            <Properties>ID</Properties>
            <Properties>ListID</Properties>
            <Properties>ModifiedDate</Properties>
            <Properties>ObjectID</Properties>
            <Properties>Status</Properties>
            <Properties>SubscriberKey</Properties>
            <Filter xsi:type="SimpleFilterPart">
               <Property>SubscriberKey</Property>
               <SimpleOperator>equals</SimpleOperator>
               <Value>aspriggs@degdigital.com</Value>
            </Filter>
            <Retrieves />
         </RetrieveRequest>
      </RetrieveRequestMsg>
   </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

**Response**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <env:Header xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
      <wsa:Action>RetrieveResponse</wsa:Action>
      <wsa:MessageID>urn:uuid:d83482e1-d2f5-47f1-8766-27adfafb91b6</wsa:MessageID>
      <wsa:RelatesTo>urn:uuid:6e8a12c5-dd24-456b-80d0-582d5506b867</wsa:RelatesTo>
      <wsa:To>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/role/anonymous</wsa:To>
      <wsse:Security>
         <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="Timestamp-8e428455-3df4-4c0f-8328-e444b9c65fa5">
            <wsu:Created>2015-01-29T17:47:17Z</wsu:Created>
            <wsu:Expires>2015-01-29T17:52:17Z</wsu:Expires>
         </wsu:Timestamp>
      </wsse:Security>
   </env:Header>
   <soap:Body>
      <RetrieveResponseMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
         <OverallStatus>OK</OverallStatus>
         <RequestID>ae5f743f-b353-464a-ab94-25ce0663aab3</RequestID>
         <Results xsi:type="ListSubscriber">
            <Client>
               <ID>XXXXXXXX</ID>
            </Client>
            <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true" />
            <CreatedDate>2014-05-13T09:19:00</CreatedDate>
            <ModifiedDate>2014-10-29T11:25:00</ModifiedDate>
            <ID>1117829630</ID>
            <ObjectID>6473212352</ObjectID>
            <Status>Unsubscribed</Status>
            <ListID>XXXXXXXX</ListID>
            <SubscriberKey>aspriggs@degdigital.com</SubscriberKey>
         </Results>
         <Results xsi:type="ListSubscriber">
            <Client>
               <ID>XXXXXXXX</ID>
            </Client>
            <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true" />
            <CreatedDate>2014-03-17T21:32:00</CreatedDate>
            <ModifiedDate>2014-10-29T11:25:00</ModifiedDate>
            <ID>1117829630</ID>
            <ObjectID>6258135573</ObjectID>
            <Status>Active</Status>
            <ListID>XXXXXXXX</ListID>
            <SubscriberKey>aspriggs@degdigital.com</SubscriberKey>
         </Results>
      </RetrieveResponseMsg>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

If that doesn't work, I'd take a look at the API user you're using and make sure it has access to the business unit.

Comment: Thanks Adam, that didn't work either (I get the same response). I'll try with another users' credentials and see if that helps. If not, it must be a config issue and I'll raise a ticket on 3Sixty. I'll keep this question open for now and once I've identified the problem I'll let you know.